# Outlook 2010 addin bind event to tab selection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I need to develop an Outlook 2010 add-in and I am new to Visual Studio and C#. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I've created a project using built-in Outlook 2010 add-in template. I've created a new ribbon and I would like to trigger an event handler when a user selects the ribbon tab. Is that possible? If yes, then what objects and what events should I use? I'd like to have some guidelines on what to do, like a sequence of instructions, 'cause I don't know where to start, really.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of i can help you there but step by step i can suggest a few links that have tutorials on doing this.
But to answer if you can trigger an event if you select the ribbon tab, yes this can be done in C# its usually .focus event.
First of lets say the code might be like this your ribbon name lets say is

```
  Ribbon ribbon1=new ribbon();
 if(ribbon.focus()==true)
 {
   messagebox.show();
   }
```

well i hope u get the idea these are the links that you 'might' :-) have missed
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226712%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163403.aspx